# Floating label over-aligning the input text

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a floating label input field, i am able to achieve but on click of outside the input, the label text is over-aligning the input field. How could i make the label on the top when there is text or cursor active in input field.

Input.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FloatingContainer, FloatingInput, FloatingLabel } from "./style.js";

export const StyledFloatingInput = () => {
  return (
    <FloatingContainer>
      <FloatingInput />
      <FloatingLabel>Text</FloatingLabel>
    </FloatingContainer>
  );
};
```

style.js

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const FloatingContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  &::before,
  &::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`;

export const FloatingInput = styled.input`
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5264ae;
  }
  &:focus ~ label {
    top: -18px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5264ae;
  }
`;

export const FloatingLabel = styled.label`
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
`;
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-glitter-big43) what i have tried so far. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `minLength="0" required` to input and and use `:valid` selector in style.

```
&:focus ~ label,
&:valid ~ label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264ae;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-frog-yrf1e)

Comment: thanks @dogukan , without required is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with only html & css without js.

Comment: If using js, how could i achieve it in react. I am new bie to this. What i am trying to create an input, select and date fields with this approach. So while starting for input itself faced this issue so could you let me know how to do with react js ?

Comment: I don't know React but you can track the input value length and set a conditional class to input. So you can use something like this`&.isOkay ~ label`

Comment: sure let me try it

Comment: i was able to achieve thanks. I am new bie to this css also, i am learning css also, is there mail id i could connect for asking my small small doubts.

Comment: What would be the right way to add a chevron icon the right of the input field ?

Comment: you can ask another question for that

Comment: Using positioning i was able to achieve thanks :)

Comment: @ dogukan I had one doubt regarding on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation If you can help me on this it will be really helpful, many thanks  

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the `:valid` selector.

Example:
https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/a24ea5ebc5ba4dee84ff470d4d7e0e81

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #1d364d;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 60px;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #8f9d9d;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #8f9d9d;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #8f9d9d;
}

.form-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 #b8c1c1;
  background-color: #f0f4f4;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.input:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 #256dd3;
}

.form-item--text .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #8f9d9d;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(15px, 8px);
}
.form-item--text .form-item__border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #256dd3;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.form-item--text .input:focus ~ .form-item__border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.form-item--text .input:focus ~ .label, .form-item--text .input:valid ~ .label {
  color: #1d364d;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translate(0, -23px);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item form-item--text">
  <input id="input" class="input input--text" type="text" required>
  <label class="label" for="input">Name</label>
  <hr class="form-item__border">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sean I had one doubt regarding on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation If you can help me on this it will be really helpful, many thanks  